# Is CoreBluetooth capable to connect with Android BLE device?

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would know if it is possible to connect CoreBluetooth with Android.
We have not, for the moment, capable devices so we cannot test.

I was not able to find a clearly answer to this question :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no Bluetooth 4.0 (which Bluetooth LE is a part of) libraries built into android right now.  In order to connect an android device to a Bluetooth 4.0 connection, you must do it for a specific device, and that device's manufacturer must have released a bluetooth 4.0 SDK.

There is an [open bluetooth low-energy SDK](http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/) for Android, but the list of supported devices is not available, and forum posts suggest it is very buggy.

Comment: It should be possible, in the future, if a "real" framework would exist someday... There is the Motorola solution, etc.<br>In my opinion, Android has bet more on NFC instead of BLE.

Comment: I can't able to access the link you provided, can you give a public access link